# Execute a program over all pairs of files in a directory using bash script

Tags: bash

I have a directory with a bunch of files. I need to create a bash file to qsub and run a program over all pairs of all files:

```
for $file1, $file2 in all_pairs
do
  /path/program -i $file1 $file2 -o $file1.$file2.result
done
```

So I could do:

```
qsub script.sh
```

to get:

```
file1.file2.result
file1.file3.result
file2.file3.result
```

for directory with:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is probably the easiest:

**the pair `a-b` is different from `b-a`:**

```
set -- file1 file2 file3 file4 ...
for f1; do 
  for f2; do 
    /path/program -i "$f1" "$f2" -o "$f1.$f2.result"
  done
done
```

**the pair `a-b` is equal to `b-a`:**

```
set -- file1 file2 file3 file4 ...
for f1; do
  shift
  for f2; do 
     /path/program -i "$f1" "$f2" -o "$f1.$f2.result"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as in every other programming language:

```
files=(file1 file2 file3) # or use a glob to list the files automatically, for instance =(*) 
max="${#files[@]}"
for ((i=0; i<max; i++)); do
  for ((j=i+1; j<max; j++)); do
    echo -i "${files[i]}" "${files[j]}" -o "${files[i]}${files[j]}.result"
  done
done
```

Replace `echo` with `/path/program` when you are happy with the result